# Read all the QR codes in an image with python

Tags: python, qr-code

I am wondering about the feasibility of the following. I worried that it wouldn't work because of camera resolution issues but let me know your thoughts.

**Background (feel free to skip)**

I am setting up a performance board that will have swim lanes. Each worker will have a number of magnets. As they move onto a new task they will place one of their magnets on the task at the appropriate time.

**Request**

Is it feasible to:

1. Take a photo of a board (say 36" x 48") containing 0.5" magnets with QR codes attached to them.
2. Then run a python script that spits out a table of co-ordinates and contents of the QR codes within the photo. The QR code would probably contain a 5-digit number or something, so could be somewhat blocky.

Are there solutions out there already that do this? What are my unknown unknowns here?

To make the question more precise:

> What resolution is needed to make out a 5 digit QR code? If a good phone camera takes a photo of a ~1m x 1.5m (3 foot x 5 foot) board, could it read a QR code that was 1cm x 1xm (0.5" x 0.5") in size.

Comment: I will start by : maybe SO is not meant for this question. Now, for your problem, there is a bunch of articles about what should the QR code size be : https://scanova.io/blog/blog/2015/02/20/qr-code-minimum-size/ . You know the resolution of the camera, you now the size of the badges, you can do the math. 
Now you're left with the question : "how to localize individual qr codes

Comment: For that question, I thing there is a lot of documentation about object detection, so many tutorials using machine learning. You could use some small logo in the center of each badge, in order to double check that you detect them all, some kind of : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbAVXSy7LxE&t=0m21s

Comment: So I guess, the answer is yes if you have the right resolution, or the right size of badges, and you manage to detect each one of them independantly

Comment: Thanks. That's extremely helpful